# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' : converting 2.7 code to 3.5

Tags: python

I am reusing a code that works in Python 2.7, but I need to rewrite it so that it works in 3.5. I am stuck when I use a pickle and I don't know how to adapt the code. I get the "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'" when I write this line of code :

```
    H = pickle.load(open("graph_40_11th.p",'r'))
```

How could I modify the code or the file so that this line runs in Python 3.5 ? I have tried the functions encode and decode but I may use them wrongly.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You need to open the file in binary mode: `open("yadadada.p", 'rb')`

Comment: Pickles are *binary data*, open the file in binary mode.